# How can I list the second to last word found in a sequence of statements in awk

Tags: awk

My file is written like:

```
apples,oranges,berries,cherries

beer,wine,shots

chocolate,icecream,cake,muffins

cherries,guacamole,lychee
```

I need to output the second to last word in lines that contain the word cherries using awk:

```
    I want it to print:
```

food: berries, guacamole

cherries appeared: 0/2 times

I currently have:

```
/cherries/

BEGIN {print "food:";}

{for (NR in a) {

FS=",";

printf($(NF-1));j++;

if((NF-1)=="cherries"){$i++;}

}

}
END {print "cherries appeared" i/j "times"}
```

What happens is it just prints every line that has cherries in it (the entire line) and $i$ comes out with a value of 0, so here it would print:

food: apples,oranges,berries,cherriescherries,guacamole,lychee

cherries appeared: nantimes

Comment: "the second to last word in lines that contain the word cherries" is inconsistent with your example output: That is the second to last word of **every** line.

Comment: oops you are right, sorry!!!! @HaukeLaging

Comment: This is very hard to understand. Could you please fix the formatting? See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help. Why should it print that `cherries` appeared 0 times? You have it twice in your file. Where do you define the `a` array? Why are you using `NR` in that loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {printf "%s","food: ";}; '\
'/cherries/ {if (matches>0) printf "%s",", "; printf "%s",$(NF-1); matches++;};'\
' END {print "";print "cherries appeared " matches "/" NR " times"}'
```

leads to this output:

```
food: berries, guacamole
cherries appeared 2/4 times
```

Comment: How is this printing the second to last word of every line containing cherries? @Hauke Laging

Comment: @WaffleMonster It doesn't. It does that how I understood the task: everything from the second word up to the last word per line. What you need is even easier...

Comment: @WaffleMonster Like what? It works here; I have added the output I get.

Comment: Maybe my problem is I have to make the whole file an awk file so I have to alter it a bit... also, I needed food: to appear before berries and guacamole, so they can all be on the same line.

What I have is:
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
/cherries/
BEGIN{print "food: "}
{printf$(NF-1);matches++;};
END{print "cherries appeared "matches "/" NR " times"}

@HaukeLaging

Comment: @WaffleMonster The awk file thing seems crazy to me. However, the output is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to count the number of times or the number of lines in which cherries appeared?

```
awk -F, '$0~k{s=s (s?", ":x) $(NF-1); t+=gsub(k,x)}
         END{printf "food: %s\n%s appeared %d/%d times\n", s, k, t, NR}
        ' k=cherries file
```

or

```
awk -F, '$0~k{s=s (s?", ":x) $(NF-1); t++}
         END{printf "food: %s\n%s appeared in %d/%d lines\n", s, k, t, NR}
        ' k=cherries file
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{ORS=",";printf "food: "} 
          /cherries/{print $(NF-1); matches++;}; 
          END{printf "\ncherries appeared "matches "/" NR " times\n"}' file 
food: berries,guacamole,
cherries appeared 2/7 times
```

Note that your file is double spaced so the number of lines includes the blank ones. To avoid this, use

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{ORS=",";printf "food: "} 
           /./{k++} 
           /cherries/{print $(NF-1); matches++;};
          END{printf "\ncherries appeared matches /" k " times\n"}' file
food: berries,guacamole,
cherries appeared matches /4 times
```

---

`-F ","` is equivalent to `FS=","`. `ORS` is the output record separator which is also set to `,` for ease of printing. The downside is that it adds an extra `,` at the end of the `food:` line but you can remove that by piping through `| sed 's/,$//'`. Your main issue was that awk's print, prints whatever you give it followed by the value of `ORS` which is a newline by default.

I don't understand what you mean by `cherries` being the penultimate field since that is never the case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "food: "}
         /cherries/ {printf $(NF-1) FS; count++}
         END{printf "\ncherries appeared %d/%d times\n", count, NR}' file
```

- `BEGIN` prints the text header.
- `/cherries/ {printf $(NF-1) FS; count++}` keeps printing the second last word on lines containing `cherries`. In that case, it also keeps track of how many lines match.
- `END` prints the summary.

For your file, it returns:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "food: "} /cherries/ {printf $(NF-1) FS; count++} END{printf "\ncherries appeared %d/%d times\n", count, NR}' file
food: berries,guacamole,
cherries appeared 2/4 times
```